# material dialog causing memory leak

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, electron, angular-material2

My app stack is angular5 and electron2, using also angular material 2.

Trying to solve a memory leak, I notice that each time a material dialog is opened, another detached DOM tree is added. I can't find anything different in my code comparing to other similar projects, which do not have this kind of behaviour.

[image]

I'v added `take(1)` to to every dialog subscription, and in general I have add `.unsubscribe()` from any subjects to components `onDestroy()`.

**edit:**

[image: added a gif showing this behaviour]

**edit:**

Follow up on github: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12114

Comment: Please provide real example where we can see this behavior

Comment: added a gif showing this behaviour: it looks like each dialog (and this happens with all dialogs across the app, not just this one) is not garbage collected after its closed, causing more and more detached DOM tree entries. it never happened to me before in other apps, I suspect its related to electron, does it make sense ? thanks